# is the @keyframes animation needs external library

Tags: css, animation, keyframe

I'm new on css animation and I'm interested to know more about @keyframe animations.

When we use @keyframe, do I need to load an external library file for that?.

I did not get the expected result when i put it alone without adding an external library?

Comment: Wall of text......

Comment: try adding some code so we can figure why it needs external library but for keyframe it does not requires external library

Comment: ok...i will post it

Comment: Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No external library is required for `keyframes` to work.

Below is the example of creating a `marquee` effect using pure CSS. Check the code snippet, it uses keyframes.

```css
.marquee-parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 30px;
}
.marquee-child {
  display: block;
  width: 147px;
  /* width of your text div */
  height: 30px;
  /* height of your text div */
  position: absolute;
  animation: marquee 5s linear infinite;
  /* change 5s value to your desired speed */
}
.marquee-child:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
  cursor: pointer;
}
@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    left: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    left: -147px
    /* same as your text width */
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="marquee-parent">
  <div class="marquee-child">
    Hover on me to stop
  </div>
</div>
```

.